# Don't suppress legend my chart

Tags: chart.js

if I have the chart legend on position left the chart will pushed to right als oif I have enough place under the legend to give the chart more place.
Does anybody knows how I use the legend with position left without suppress the chart?

```
$(function(){
  //chartJS
        var canvas = $('#graph')[0];
        var time = 0.15;
        var projectTime = 0.95;
        var config = {
            type: "doughnut",
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        time,
                        projectTime
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
                            "rgb(201, 203, 207)"
                        ],
                        label: "Dataset 1"
                    }],
                    labels: [
                        "Aktueller Eintrag (" + time + ")",
                        "Projekt Zeit (" + projectTime + ")"
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: "left"
                    },
                    animation: {
                        animateRotate: true
                    }
                }
            }

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

[Chart Demo of my code](https://jsbin.com/nidufo/latest/edit?html,css,js,output)

On my picture you can see what I mean. It looks not so nice if the legend have only two entries.

[Chart with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkoNb.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: I have edit my Answer with an Example of my code.